# Objective-C interface Named "Category" cannot be imported into swift via the bridging header

Tags: swift, objective-c, core-data, bridging-header

The below swift code throws this error ('Category' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context)

```
// ctx is the UIContext, fetchCategories is an Obj-C function that queries CoreData 
//for the Categories, the cast shouldn't even be necessary but swift will not 
//recognize my obj-c interface

if let cats = self.fetchCategories(ctx) {  
  let array = cats as! [Category] //error happens on this line
  return array
}
```

This is the implementation in my bridging header,
there are many other imports but I removed them for this post, so note that it is a fully functional bridging header for almost 40 other .h files

```
#ifndef AppDataRoom_Bridging_Header_h
#define AppDataRoom_Bridging_Header_h

#import "Category.h"

#endif /* AppDataRoom_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Below is the interface implementation

```
@interface Category : _Category <QLPreviewItem> {
  UIImage *squareThumb;
}
```

I realize that changing the name of the Category class would be the best option since this is probably due to the naming convention being common,  However when I change the code to this :

```
if let cats = self.fetchCategories(ctx) {  
  let array = cats as! [<ModuleName>.Category] //error happens on this line
  return array
}
```

Is still says it is too ambiguous to lookup.  Any ideas on other things I could try besides changing the interface name, because that really isn't an option and I will spare you all the reasons why.

Comment: Do you have more than one `Category` declarations? Either `@interface`, or `typedef`?

Comment: No I do not! I resolved this by changing the name of my Core Data Object to something more specific. Which I still haven't figured out how to migrate the Core Data base but that is an entirely different problem.